# CSS to JQuery: converting hover to click? (JSFiddle)

Tags: jquery, css, hover

How can I convert this CSS-based hover menu to click? I assume JQuery is the cleanest way but I'm having a hard time to toggling classes because it only opens the menu for a split second. Any help would be great.

**http://jsfiddle.net/PrtvG/**

**HTML**

```
<div id="navi1" class="navi">
    <ul><li><a href="">Link1</a></li><li class="sel"><a href="">Link2</a></li><li><a href="">Link3</a></li><li><a href="">Link4</a></li><li><a href="">Link5</a></li><li><a href="">Link6</a></li><li><a href="">Link7</a></li><li><a href="">Link8</a></li></ul>
</div>
<div id="navi2" class="navi">
    <ul><li><a href="">Link1</a></li><li class="sel"><a href="">Link2</a></li><li><a href="">Link3</a></li><li><a href="">Link4</a></li><li><a href="">Link5</a></li><li><a href="">Link6</a></li><li><a href="">Link7</a></li><li><a href="">Link8</a></li></ul>
</div>
<div id="navi3" class="navi">
    <ul><li><a href="">Link1</a></li><li class="sel"><a href="">Link2</a></li><li><a href="">Link3</a></li><li><a href="">Link4</a></li><li><a href="">Link5</a></li><li><a href="">Link6</a></li><li><a href="">Link7</a></li><li><a href="">Link8</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why switch from CSS to jQuery?

Comment: Is there a clean way to activate this menu on click and not hover using CSS?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/